# Spring framework IDE - where to learn efficently?

Tags: spring, ide, netbeans

im looking at spring right now and im not sure how to use it in most efficent way as im not sure if it does not have some features or do i need some special way to enable them.

Question: What resources would you recommend to pick up quickly the tools necessary for quick and easy java jsf/spring development?

Some of the problems i saw so far:

1. Spring IDE does not help me in beans.xml. In netbeans once i add schemas to my netbeans.xml i have very pretty auto completion so that beans xml becomes really quick and easy, does spring ide have this kind of feature? how do i enable it?
2. validation - seems like i can easily make mistakes in the app configuration and things like misspelled beans, calss names in xml etc go unnoticed untill the runtime. Is there any way to enable better validation for this kind of problem? I can see netbeans is bad at it asa well. EL is not validated, benas in jsf projects are not validated. Many things that could be checked fail in runtime.
3. in netbeans EL auto completion does not work for some of my beans

etc

Answer (score 0):

Mannings *Spring in Action* book (http://www.manning.com/walls3/) is an excellent resource for getting into the Spring framework.

Comment: I probably mis-understood, but actually no big tool support is required for Spring except for a reasonable XML editor. Especially the tools do not really help you to learn Spring.